# why is my regular expression not working in IE7?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following code to check the special character in a text box.

```
var partial = /[*!@#$%^&*~]/;
var check = function (string) {
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (partial.test(string[i])) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

//onclick I am calling the below one

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    if (check($(this).val()) == true || $(this).val().length <= 2) {
        //displayerrormessage
        noerror += 1;
    }
});
```

It works in all browser but not in IE7.
I am not sure what I need to change.

Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a legitimate question. @svk can you please format your code?

Comment: checking with each char using `test` is **not** required...you can simply use `exec` method on complete string

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: `This is a legitimate question` Someone could down-vote if they think the question is either not useful, does not show any research effort or is unclear. In someone elses opinion this question may or may not have fallen under any of those categories. I didn't down-vote but I'm only saying. Not all users share the same opinion of quality or usefullness :)

Comment: @The_Land_Of_Devils_SriLanka he could also use test on the whole string too. svk, could you provide a string for which the test showed a wrong behavior?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 7 doesn't support accessing strings by index.

You have to use the `charAt` method to be compatible with IE7:

```
partial.test(string.charAt(i))
```